# How to install or upgrade package with yum with a zero exit code?

Tags: yum

I'm working on a script to install a package from a URL. The script needs to install the package if it isn't installed and forcibly replace the existing version with the specified RPM if it is already installed. Unfortunately both `yum install` and `yum update` return 1 if the package is already at the right version. **How do I just tell `yum` to absolutely, positively install an RPM and only return an exit code if there's an *actual error?***

Comment: do you mean allowing downgrades, or actually reinstalling even when EVR is the same?

Comment: Delete the package first? ;-)

Comment: @guido Reinstalling is not necessary, but it must definitely allow downgrades.

Comment: did you already try `yum --allow-downgrade install <package-version>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of your script calling `yum` to do the download and install, I would just make the script download the file (with e.g. `curl` or `wget`) and then force the installation of the downloaded `.rpm` file:

```
rpm --install --force file_name.rpm
```

As the OP indicated, `rpm` can donwload the URL directly without a problem. From the man page:

```
INSTALLING, UPGRADING, AND REMOVING PACKAGES:
   rpm {-i|--install} [install-options] PACKAGE_FILE ...

   rpm {-U|--upgrade} [install-options] PACKAGE_FILE ...

   rpm {-F|--freshen} [install-options] PACKAGE_FILE ...

   <snip>

   In  these  options, PACKAGE_FILE can be either rpm binary file or ASCII
   package manifest (see PACKAGE SELECTION OPTIONS), and may be  specified
   as  an  ftp  or  http URL, in which case the package will be downloaded
   before being installed. See FTP/HTTP OPTIONS for information  on  rpm's
   internal ftp and http client support.
```

Comment: I agree here, unless the OP is doing no dependency checking...

Comment: @eyoung100 If that could be a problem, first installing with `yum` from the local download should get any missing dependencies, and then if that fails, because of already being up-to-date, do the forced RPM install. That's still only one download.

Comment: `rpm` seems to be fine installing from URLs. Why would I need to download first? Anyway, your command works. Thanks!

Comment: @l0b0 I currently don't have an RPM based system running and I have been using Debian packaging for too long. I thought I remembered that `rpm` could only install locally. (I used to have a SuSE system, where YaST would download and install from the net, I used `rpm` only for locally created `.rpm` files).

Comment: what if the downgraded package needs a to-be-downgraded dependency?